# uib-datepicker angular js not showing datetime with specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime, datepicker

I'm working in asp.net core application with angular js 1.6.

When i'm trying to binding a scope model with  specific format in ui datepikcher angular the value not showing in component.

The format of datetime in my model is:
 2017-10-25T12:53:18.833

The code of my datepicker in html file is:

```
<input id="dateDebut" type="text" 
  date-validator class="form-control" datepicker-popup-custom="{{dateFormat}}" 
  datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-model="role.DateDebut" on-open-focus="false" 
  is-open="calendrierRole.dateDebut.opened" close-text="{{labels.FERMER}}"
  ng-required="true" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
    ng-click="openCalendrierRole('dateDebut')">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

But when the format of my date is : Fri Oct 27 2017 10:00:33 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time) => the value is showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions
A. add this in the input

```
uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
```

change the format that u want
B. create angular service that return the input value as Date object

```
function getDate(date) {
 return new Date(date);
};
```

then add the service 'getDate' to the input.
Good luck

Comment: i have choose the second solution but I got this error: 
 Error: ngModel:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression